# Access to field results in dereference of a null pointer in C

Tags: c++, c, pointers, compiler-errors, structure

This question is related to C Programming Language:
I get error: Access to field 'x' results in a dereference of null pointer

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct A {  
    int *x;  
    int *y;  
} A;  

void allocateStruct(int sizeN, A *aType);
void printInfo(A *aType);
  
int main() {   
    A *genericA;  
    allocateStruct(5, genericA);  
    int x[5] = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6};  
    int y[5] = {12, 36, 40, 52, 23};   

    genericA->x = x;  
    genericA->y = y;  
    printInfo(genericA);   
}  

void allocateStruct(int sizeN, A* aType) {  
    aType->x = (int*)malloc(sizeN * sizeof(int));   
    aType->y = (int*)malloc(sizeN * sizeof(int));    
}  
 
void printInfo(A *aType) { 
    printf("%i %i\n",  aType->x[0], aType->y[0] ); 
}
```

Comment: For one, replace `genericA.x = x; genericA.y = y;` with `genericA->x = x; genericA->y = y;`

Comment: Now `A *genericA;` is an unintialised pointer. So `aType->x`, `genericA->x`, etc are dereferncing garbage values. Perhaps you should tell us what result you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Maybe you want: `A genericA; allocateStruct(5, &genericA); memcpy(genericA->x, x, sizeof(x));`.

Comment: @kaylum In my program, sizeN will change frequently. In this case I am using 5. So I want to dynamically allocate the size to  aType->x and aType->y. Your suggestion do I put it in main or in allocateStruct and get rid of mallocs?

Comment: Yes well you are still doing that in `allocateStruct`. I never mentioned getting rid of `malloc`. Why do you think the code I gave you will not dynamically allocate the `x` and `y` fields?

Comment: Can you elaborate little bit where memcpy(genericA->x, x, sizeof(x)); should go. Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You haven't allocated a memory to the structure and yet you are accessing it's member in

```
void allocateStruct(int sizeN, A* aType) {
    aType->x = (int*)malloc(sizeN * sizeof(int));   
    aType->y = (int*)malloc(sizeN * sizeof(int));    
}
```

allocate memory to the structure itself first

```
atype = malloc(sizeof(A))
```

You need to return the address of atype to your main function as you are passing the pointer by value else your changes in allocateStruct wont be accessible in main and also cause a memory leak. You don't need to pass atype as a parameter in case you are returning the address.

```
A* allocateStruct(int sizeN){
    A* atype;
    atype = malloc(sizeof(A));
    aType->x = malloc(sizeN * sizeof(int));   
    aType->y = malloc(sizeN * sizeof(int)); 
    return atype;
}
```

and in main

```
atype = allocateStruct(5);
```

Also you dont need to typecast explicitly in C, the malloc returns a void pointer and it can be assigned to any type. And also for completeness so that you dont cause memory leaks at the end of main just free all your memory that you have malloced.

```
free(atype->x);
free(atype->y);
free(atype);
```

Comment: can you suggest where should I add atype = malloc(sizeof(A)). Would it be between these two lines `` A *genericA;  
    allocateStruct(5, genericA); ``

Comment: the first line of your allocateStruct function should be better, its always good to write your code in the function which has the most suitable name for it.

Comment: `atype = malloc(sizeof(A))` will not set the caller's pointer variable because `atype` is local to the function. That is, `genericA` in `main` will still be uninitialised after that.

Comment: ah yes. You will also need to return the pointer atype. that should fix it.

Comment: Suggest you show the actual correct code. Not just show wrong code and say how it should be fixed.

Comment: yeah, either this or pass the pointer by reference and return void.

Comment: @RinkeshP good point about the memory leak.  If you can show the code, would be helpful.

Comment: @RinkeshP Just wanted to ask if you can explain this step: atype = malloc(sizeof(A));   [Code is working, just want to understand what this step is doing.]

Comment: the same thing what other malloc statements are doing, allocating memory and providing a pointer to it. atype in main is a struct pointer so without having it pointing to a struct in memory, you cant access whats supposed to be inside that struct.